# How do I change a sprite using code from another node?

Tags: sprites, godot, card-game

I'm trying to make a program in Godot where the player can put a bunch of images into a folder, and when the button is pressed, have the image appear as a sprite on the screen. With the current code, the directory for the image is printed when the button is pressed, but the image sprite simply does not appear. No error messages come up either, so I'm stumped as to what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
extends Button

func _pressed():
    var cards_order = [] #creates the array
    
    var path = "assets/cards/" #defines a path
    var dir = Directory.new() #creates a directory
    dir.open(path) #sets the directory to the defined path
    dir.list_dir_begin() #begins listing the directory
    while true:
        var file_name = dir.get_next() #sets the var "file_name" to the next entry in the directory
        if file_name == "":
        #break the while loop when get_next() returns ""
            break
        elif !file_name.begins_with(".") && !file_name.ends_with(".import"):
        #get_next() returns a string so this can be used to load the images into an array. Also stops .import files from being added
            cards_order.append(load(path + file_name)) #loads the next file into the array
    dir.list_dir_end()
    
    randomize() #changes the randomization
    
    cards_order.shuffle() #shuffles the array
    
    var card_sprite = cards_order.front() #sets card_sprite as the first item in the array
    
    print(card_sprite.get_path())
    
    $"/root/CardSprite".texture = load(card_sprite.get_path())
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!